# WiFi not working on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: networking, intel-wireless

I'm getting the following results after running the wireless info script:

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 28 Jan 2017 00:54 IST +0530

Booted last: 27 Jan 2017 19:28 IST +0530

Script from: 08 Jul 2016 02:16 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

##### kernel ############################

Linux 3.13.0-38-generic #65somerville1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 15 02:15:02 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, locale=en_IN, quiet, splash, radeon.modeset=0, nouveau.modeset=0, video.use_native_backlight=1, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 [8086:08b3] (rev 83)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless AC 3160 [8086:8470]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi

07:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:06b0]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:5683 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

iwlmvm                189813  0 
mac80211              626557  1 iwlmvm
dell_wmi               12761  0 
sparse_keymap          13948  1 dell_wmi
dell_laptop            18168  0 
dcdbas                 14928  1 dell_laptop
iwlwifi               169932  1 iwlmvm
cfg80211              484040  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwlmvm
wmi                    19177  2 dell_led,dell_wmi

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eth0' [IF1]>  
          inet addr:192.168.1.102  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::<IP6 'eth0' [IF1]>/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:447498 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:338214 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:597789847 (597.7 MB)  TX bytes:37258224 (37.2 MB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:238297 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:189734 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:331915821 (331.9 MB)  TX bytes:20432875 (20.4 MB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on


##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root      1078     1  0 Jan27 ?        00:00:05 NetworkManager

##### NetworkManager info ###############

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: eth0  [Wired connection 1] -------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            r8169
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        <MAC 'eth0' [IF1]>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes
    Speed:           100 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         on

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.1.102
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.1.1

    DNS:             8.8.8.8
    DNS:             172.16.0.1

- Device: wlan0 ----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            iwlwifi
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        <MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>

  Capabilities:

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points 

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=false
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/SHIVA]] (600 root)
[connection] id=SHIVA | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=SHIVA | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/C1st(b)]] (600 root)
[connection] id=C1st(b) | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=C1st(b) | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/C-1st(a)]] (600 root)
[connection] id=C-1st(a) | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=C-1st(a) | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Asia/Kolkata (based on set time zone)

country 00:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (3, 20)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (3, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS

##### iwlist channels ###################

eth0      no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

wlan0     32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
          Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
          Channel 108 : 5.54 GHz
          Channel 112 : 5.56 GHz
          Channel 116 : 5.58 GHz
          Channel 120 : 5.6 GHz
          Channel 124 : 5.62 GHz
          Channel 128 : 5.64 GHz
          Channel 132 : 5.66 GHz
          Channel 136 : 5.68 GHz
          Channel 140 : 5.7 GHz

##### iwlist scan #######################

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlan0     Interface doesn't support scanning : Network is down

##### module infos ######################

[iwlmvm]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-38-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/mvm/iwlmvm.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003-2013 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
version:        in-tree:
description:    The new Intel(R) wireless AGN driver for Linux
srcversion:     7AF85C9FBD17AD993F1CC33
depends:        iwlwifi,mac80211,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-38-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        04:AD:CA:E0:24:C0:38:DD:69:A4:B6:6B:29:B3:E8:78:11:D4:E3:81
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           init_dbg:set to true to debug an ASSERT in INIT fw (default: false (bool)
parm:           power_scheme:power management scheme: 1-active, 2-balanced, 3-low power, default: 2 (int)

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-38-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     123C230E7AC85A31E4CA28B
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-38-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        04:AD:CA:E0:24:C0:38:DD:69:A4:B6:6B:29:B3:E8:78:11:D4:E3:81
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[iwlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-38-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003-2013 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
version:        in-tree:
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-7.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-7.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode
srcversion:     783BEDE878FE84FE74C8D63
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-38-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        04:AD:CA:E0:24:C0:38:DD:69:A4:B6:6B:29:B3:E8:78:11:D4:E3:81
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm:           amsdu_size_8K:enable 8K amsdu size (default 0) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm:           antenna_coupling:specify antenna coupling in dB (defualt: 0 dB) (int)
parm:           wd_disable:Disable stuck queue watchdog timer 0=system default, 1=disable, 2=enable (default: 0) (int)
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.13.0-38-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     C2478077E22138832B71659
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.13.0-38-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        04:AD:CA:E0:24:C0:38:DD:69:A4:B6:6B:29:B3:E8:78:11:D4:E3:81
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[iwlmvm]
init_dbg: N
power_scheme: 2

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
probe_wait_ms: 500

[iwlwifi]
11n_disable: 0
amsdu_size_8K: 0
antenna_coupling: 0
bt_coex_active: Y
fw_restart: Y
led_mode: 0
nvm_file: (null)
power_level: 0
power_save: N
swcrypto: 0
wd_disable: 1

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

lp
rtc
lp
rtc

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-i2c_hid.conf]
blacklist i2c_hid

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

[/etc/pm/power.d/disable_wol] (777 root)
CONFFILE=/etc/default/tlp
LIBDIRS='/usr/lib /usr/lib64'
for d in ${LIBDIRS}; do
    if [ -d "${d}/pm-utils/power.d" ]; then
        blocked="${d}/pm-utils/power.d/${0##*/}"
        break
    fi
done
if [ -n "$blocked" ] && [ -x "$blocked" ]; then
    # else nothing to disable -> don't read $CONFFILE
    if [ -e "$CONFFILE" ] && . "$CONFFILE" -- && [ "$TLP_ENABLE" = '1' ]; then
        # TLP is enabled -> disable $blocked
        echo "Notice: '${blocked}' disabled by TLP."
    else
        exec "$blocked" $*
    fi
fi
exit 0

[/etc/pm/power.d/laptop-mode] (777 root)
CONFFILE=/etc/default/tlp
LIBDIRS='/usr/lib /usr/lib64'
for d in ${LIBDIRS}; do
    if [ -d "${d}/pm-utils/power.d" ]; then
        blocked="${d}/pm-utils/power.d/${0##*/}"
        break
    fi
done
if [ -n "$blocked" ] && [ -x "$blocked" ]; then
    # else nothing to disable -> don't read $CONFFILE
    if [ -e "$CONFFILE" ] && . "$CONFFILE" -- && [ "$TLP_ENABLE" = '1' ]; then
        # TLP is enabled -> disable $blocked
        echo "Notice: '${blocked}' disabled by TLP."
    else
        exec "$blocked" $*
    fi
fi
exit 0

[/etc/pm/power.d/pci_devices] (777 root)
CONFFILE=/etc/default/tlp
LIBDIRS='/usr/lib /usr/lib64'
for d in ${LIBDIRS}; do
    if [ -d "${d}/pm-utils/power.d" ]; then
        blocked="${d}/pm-utils/power.d/${0##*/}"
        break
    fi
done
if [ -n "$blocked" ] && [ -x "$blocked" ]; then
    # else nothing to disable -> don't read $CONFFILE
    if [ -e "$CONFFILE" ] && . "$CONFFILE" -- && [ "$TLP_ENABLE" = '1' ]; then
        # TLP is enabled -> disable $blocked
        echo "Notice: '${blocked}' disabled by TLP."
    else
        exec "$blocked" $*
    fi
fi
exit 0

[/etc/pm/power.d/pcie_aspm] (777 root)
CONFFILE=/etc/default/tlp
LIBDIRS='/usr/lib /usr/lib64'
for d in ${LIBDIRS}; do
    if [ -d "${d}/pm-utils/power.d" ]; then
        blocked="${d}/pm-utils/power.d/${0##*/}"
        break
    fi
done
if [ -n "$blocked" ] && [ -x "$blocked" ]; then
    # else nothing to disable -> don't read $CONFFILE
    if [ -e "$CONFFILE" ] && . "$CONFFILE" -- && [ "$TLP_ENABLE" = '1' ]; then
        # TLP is enabled -> disable $blocked
        echo "Notice: '${blocked}' disabled by TLP."
    else
        exec "$blocked" $*
    fi
fi
exit 0

[/etc/pm/power.d/sched-powersave] (777 root)
CONFFILE=/etc/default/tlp
LIBDIRS='/usr/lib /usr/lib64'
for d in ${LIBDIRS}; do
    if [ -d "${d}/pm-utils/power.d" ]; then
        blocked="${d}/pm-utils/power.d/${0##*/}"
        break
    fi
done
if [ -n "$blocked" ] && [ -x "$blocked" ]; then
    # else nothing to disable -> don't read $CONFFILE
    if [ -e "$CONFFILE" ] && . "$CONFFILE" -- && [ "$TLP_ENABLE" = '1' ]; then
        # TLP is enabled -> disable $blocked
        echo "Notice: '${blocked}' disabled by TLP."
    else
        exec "$blocked" $*
    fi
fi
exit 0

[/etc/pm/power.d/usb_bluetooth] (777 root)
CONFFILE=/etc/default/tlp
LIBDIRS='/usr/lib /usr/lib64'
for d in ${LIBDIRS}; do
    if [ -d "${d}/pm-utils/power.d" ]; then
        blocked="${d}/pm-utils/power.d/${0##*/}"
        break
    fi
done
if [ -n "$blocked" ] && [ -x "$blocked" ]; then
    # else nothing to disable -> don't read $CONFFILE
    if [ -e "$CONFFILE" ] && . "$CONFFILE" -- && [ "$TLP_ENABLE" = '1' ]; then
        # TLP is enabled -> disable $blocked
        echo "Notice: '${blocked}' disabled by TLP."
    else
        exec "$blocked" $*
    fi
fi
exit 0

[/etc/pm/power.d/wireless] (777 root)
CONFFILE=/etc/default/tlp
LIBDIRS='/usr/lib /usr/lib64'
for d in ${LIBDIRS}; do
    if [ -d "${d}/pm-utils/power.d" ]; then
        blocked="${d}/pm-utils/power.d/${0##*/}"
        break
    fi
done
if [ -n "$blocked" ] && [ -x "$blocked" ]; then
    # else nothing to disable -> don't read $CONFFILE
    if [ -e "$CONFFILE" ] && . "$CONFFILE" -- && [ "$TLP_ENABLE" = '1' ]; then
        # TLP is enabled -> disable $blocked
        echo "Notice: '${blocked}' disabled by TLP."
    else
        exec "$blocked" $*
    fi
fi
exit 0

[/etc/pm/power.d/xfs_buffer] (777 root)
CONFFILE=/etc/default/tlp
LIBDIRS='/usr/lib /usr/lib64'
for d in ${LIBDIRS}; do
    if [ -d "${d}/pm-utils/power.d" ]; then
        blocked="${d}/pm-utils/power.d/${0##*/}"
        break
    fi
done
if [ -n "$blocked" ] && [ -x "$blocked" ]; then
    # else nothing to disable -> don't read $CONFFILE
    if [ -e "$CONFFILE" ] && . "$CONFFILE" -- && [ "$TLP_ENABLE" = '1' ]; then
        # TLP is enabled -> disable $blocked
        echo "Notice: '${blocked}' disabled by TLP."
    else
        exec "$blocked" $*
    fi
fi
exit 0

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8136 (r8169)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'eth0' [IF1]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
# PCI device 0x8086:0x08b3 (iwlwifi)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

##### dmesg #############################

[ 5241.938665] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.0.1.2d.d.bseq
[ 5242.009628] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware patch completed and activated
[ 5243.285618] iwlwifi 0000:06:00.0: L1 Enabled; Disabling L0S (repeated 2 times)
[ 5243.297564] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[ 5243.538649] r8169 0000:07:00.0 eth0: link down
[ 5243.538695] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[ 5250.852433] wlan0: authenticate with <MAC address>
[ 5250.854757] wlan0: direct probe to <MAC address> (try 1/3)
[ 5251.055565] wlan0: direct probe to <MAC address> (try 2/3)
[ 5251.259875] wlan0: direct probe to <MAC address> (try 3/3)
[ 5251.462756] wlan0: authentication with <MAC address> timed out
[ 5950.473430] r8169 0000:07:00.0 eth0: link up
[ 5950.473553] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[ 5950.478319] r8169 0000:07:00.0 eth0: link up
[ 9816.472322] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[13484.924190] r8169 0000:07:00.0 eth0: link down
[13489.441904] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[13934.309508] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[14115.723031] r8169 0000:07:00.0 eth0: link down
[14117.250382] r8169 0000:07:00.0 eth0: link up
[14117.250398] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: what do you believe to achieve with this wall of text?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** What is not working exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your Wifi Adapter is soft blocked. try these commands one by one-

```
sudo rmmod -f iwlwifi
sudo rfkill unblock all
sudo modprobe iwlwifi
```

I used this solution to fix my friend's laptop with athk5 wifi kernel since u have iwlwifi kernel these commands might work for you. also if you have a key to turn your wifi on or off try that too. in my case its fn+F2 it might be different for you